# Add param to dagster input

Tags: python, dagster

Hello I have the following @job in dagster

```
@job
def job_extract_faces():
    faces = op_extract_data(op_get_data_path())
    r = op_process((faces, 'a'))
    r = op_process((faces, 'b'))
    r = op_process((faces, 'c'))
    r = op_process((faces, 'd'))
```

the proble is that dagster says that the input of the op_process should be the output of op_extrac_data

is there anyway of add a parameter instead of build 4 functions?

thhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Dynamic Graphs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/dynamic-graphs#dynamic-graphs). Using this pattern you'd emit your parameters as DynamicOutputs from an upstream op and map that output across `op_process`. One option would be to do something like:

```
from dagster import op, job, DynamicOut, DynamicOutput


@op(config_schema={"param_list": [str]},
    out=DynamicOut(str))
def param_generator(context):
    for i, p in enumerate(context.op_config["param_list"]):
        yield DynamicOutput(p, mapping_key=str(i))

@job
def job_extract_faces():
    faces = op_extract_data(op_get_data_path())
    param_generator().map(lambda p: op_process(faces, p))
```

This is similar to the mapping example in the docs showing how to do [dynamic mapping with additional arguments](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/dynamic-graphs#additional-arguments)